# FOIA request for full NSF awards proposal and report

Tags: funding, nsf

*Related to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122374/where-to-find-nsf-reports-for-mathematical-expository-purpose) on mathoverflow…*

Indeed, I just found out that to see full proposal or later reports. One needs to file a FOIA request, as described [here](http://www.nsf.gov/policies/foia.jsp).

So I am curious if anyone has done so? And how is the process like?
In particular, can the requester remain confidential after the request (so other people will not know that I made the request)?

Additional follow up question: What kind of people can file FOIA request? Does it have to be US citizens? Or just anyone working in US? etc..

Comment: Actually, one only _needs_ to file a FOIA request if your polite request to the PI is turned down.  **Ask the PI first.**

Comment: Just for record. For the follow up question. "Any U.S. citizen, foreign national, foreign government, state government, partnership, corporation, or association may make a FOIA request. Agencies are not required to process FOIA requests made by fugitives from justice or by an agency acting on behalf of a fugitive"

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The name of the requester does not remain confidential.

A friend of mine was recently on the other end.  NSF contacted him to tell him that an FOIA request had been made for a copy of his proposal, told him the name of the requester, and asked whether the proposal contained any sensitive information that he wished to have redacted.

The general feeling was that making such a request, rather than contacting the PI directly, was unprofessional and borderline creepy.  I second JeffE's comment: **Ask the PI first.**

Comment: Definitely, filing a FOIA request without even asking the PI is incredibly unprofessional and creepy.  But I'd actually go further and say filing a FOIA request at all is more than a little creepy, even if you asked and the PI refused to send you the proposal.  In most cases it's an abuse of the FOIA system.  (If you are doing it to investigate what the government is funding, then that's a legitimate use.  If you are doing it to try to get a behind-the-scenes view of a competitor's research program, then that's unethical.)

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician: Well, I'm rather surprised at the comment! Say you are writing a grant that didn't get through, and you'd like to understand what the successful proposals had that you didn't - then, wouldn't you want to know what they contained? You may not have the best of relations with the author, who may even view you as a competitor, but since its ultimately funded by the taxpayers, I imagine that shouldn't affect your ability to learn from it?

Comment: I can understand wanting to see some successful proposals, but there's no need to see specific ones for that purpose.  If you ask around, maybe not everyone will agree to share their proposal, but many people will and you'll get plenty of proposals to learn from.  In particular, the ones you do see will be perfectly good examples of proposal writing.  FOIA requests are needed only if someone insists on seeing specific proposals that the PI isn't comfortable showing them.  To me, that strongly suggests that they are trying to study unpublished plans or information, which is unethical.

Comment: I guess maybe I'd analyze it as follows.  People such as reviewers or panel members have access to NSF proposals, and they are strictly forbidden from taking advantage of this confidential information.  I see someone making a FOIA request as being in a similar situation.  They are legally entitled to see the proposal, but scientific ethics do not permit them to use unpublished ideas or data taken from it.  Deliberately requesting information you cannot ethically use looks suspicious.

Comment: @TCSGrad: You want to see a successful grant proposal?  Send me an email.  Really.

Comment: Also, the PI and their institution's lawyers can censor anything of possible commercial value before sending you the proposal.  (Or so my university's lawyers have told my colleagues who have been FOIA'd.)  So if the PI is _really_ offended by the FOIA request, you might just receive 15 pages of black rectangles.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician: Well, that clears it up a lot more :) - true, most people may not object to showing grant proposals that are 5-10 years old, which still has enough information for someone new to the field!

Comment: @JeffE: I had actually downloaded your NSF CAREER proposal from your website, as a reference for a successful grant  - I'll definitely email you for some of the other grants you've listed on your homepage once I feel I've sufficiently assimilated that one!

Comment: Actually the motivation for me is to learn what other people are doing (imagine not everyone will explain in email in detail what they are doing!). My initial thought is that since NSF is a public organization, supposedly everything should be public and free. But apparently it has some restrictions... I am still curious though... In fact, why would PI put any "sensitive" information in the proposal anyway...

Comment: Additional follow up question: What kind of people can file FOIA request? Does it have to be US citizens? Or just anyone working in US? etc..

Comment: By the way, some people put almost all their full proposal on the website. For example, William Stein, http://modular.math.washington.edu/grants/  This again says my point---why would anyone put "sensitive" information in their grant proposal?

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician: whether creepy or not, realize that if the research is funded by the public, **the public has a right to see what it funds**. Unless there is a reason to consider parts of the material confidential.

Comment: @walkmanyi: I certainly think that the public has a right to see the results of research that they fund, and indeed I support open access mandates that require that funded papers be made public.  However, there's a big difference between the results of funded research and the grant proposals themselves.  The proposals include ideas which don't pan out (which could be embarrassing) and ideas which take time to work out (which could get stolen).

Comment: _Actually the motivation for me is to learn what other people are doing_ — Read their papers.  Go to their talks.  Or just ask them.

Comment: @walkmanyi: Certainly the public has a legal right to investigate what's being funded, but there's no academic right to use unpublished information from grant proposals.  Research plans and ideas, partial progress, etc. are by default confidential.  Some people are happy to share them with the world, and I think this is often sensible, but others care about confidentiality.  If you learn confidential information about someone else's research program, you cannot use this information yourself or refer to it.  You must act as if you had never learned it, which is sometimes easier said than done.

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician: IANAL, but there seems to be an interesting interplay between the concept of confidentiality and release of information through FOIA-like requests. I wouldn't be surprised if the "confidentiality" we refer here would be only a vague concept without any legal backing. And even if not, I guess the material looses whatever confidentiality status upon release through a FOIA-like request. Consider journalists who normally refer to such materials and use them to advance their own careers. But of course, I see you point.

Comment: You're right that there is no legal protection, but this is true for lots of academic norms.  For example, there are no laws specifying who should be an author of an academic paper.  If you collaborate with someone, you are legally entitled to secretly write and publish a singly-authored paper describing your findings and just thanking them in the body of the paper.  However, academia would judge this harshly.  Similarly, it would be legal to obtain someone else's grant proposal against their wishes, develop their ideas yourself, and publish them, but it would be unethical.

Comment: (Journalism is a special case, because one aspect of investigative journalism is identifying cases where violating some form of confidentiality is justified for the good of society.  Similarly, if you discovered that someone else's research project was endangering people, it would be reasonable to violate confidentiality to avert the danger.)

Answer (score 14):

OK. Now I have some **very clear answer**. The list of all requesters is in fact **PUBLISHED** on NSF website.

See, for example, all NSF FOIA request in 2010 (PDF)
http://www.nsf.gov/policies/2010_FOIA_LOG.pdf

The link is found at the bottom of this page:
http://www.nsf.gov/policies/foia.jsp

Comment: This is a really interesting list.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Wow, the stories that must be behind some of those.  Example: On 10/23/2009, Mark Spaulding of "Federal Prison" requested "All available disclosable data on
very large industrial lasers, especially as applied to the mining industry." :-O

Comment: @NateEldredge I think he may be an employee there, and what he requested just his personal hobby.. :) In fact "Any U.S. citizen, foreign national, foreign government, state government, partnership, corporation, or association may make a FOIA request. Agencies are not required to process FOIA requests made by fugitives from justice or by an agency acting on behalf of a fugitive."

Comment: @rptr: I bet that's just what Auric Goldfinger wants you to think.  (By the way, prison inmates are not fugitives.)